# WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0 not able to use TLSv1.2 when integrating with AWS SES

Tags: wso2-api-manager, tls1.2, wso2-identity-server, amazon-ses

We are currently using WSO2am version 2.6.0 and have not yet upgraded to a more recent version.

Deploying the application with Java8. Since AWS SES no longer accepts anything lower than TLSv1.2 we are seeing issues with sending out emails when reseting passwords.

Has anyone been able to force TLSv1.2 for WSO2am email clients?

I have seen some posts related to updating the email adapter config in the "output-event-adapters.xml" to force the use to TLSv1.2.

Like so.

```
<adapterConfig type="email">
    <property key="smtp.from">your-email@example.com</property>
    <property key="smtp.username">your-username</property>
    <property key="smtp.password">your-password</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.ssl.protocols">TLSv1.2</property>
    <!-- Other email properties -->
</adapterConfig>
```

This does not work unfortunately, we have also tried adding the TLS version as a JVM parameter, this also has not worked.

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Stack Trace Error

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 Access denied: Amazon SES no longer supports TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 connections. You must update your client to use TLS version 1.2 or above. To learn more and to update your client, see https://go.aws/3AUlVSb. For further assistance, contact AWS support
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set the parameter using single quotes in the key attribute:

```xml
<adapterConfig type="email">
    <property key="smtp.from">your-email@example.com</property>
    <property key="smtp.username">your-username</property>
    <property key="smtp.password">your-password</property>
    <property key="'mail.smtp.ssl.protocols'">TLSv1.2</property>
    <!-- Other email properties -->
</adapterConfig>
```

I encountered similar issues when configuring a JMS connection with Tibco EMS, where some parameters weren't exported from the config (deployment.toml). The solution at the time was to single-quote the parameter. For example, from:

```
name = "SenderTIBCOFactory_topic"
parameter.initial_naming_factory = "com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory"
parameter.provider_url = "{{tibcoems.provider_url}}"
parameter.connection_factory_name = "{{tibcoems.topics_factory_name}}"
parameter.jms_spec_version = "1.0.2b"
parameter.connection_factory_type = "topic"
parameter.security.principal = "{{tibcoems.username}}"
parameter.security.credentials = "{{tibcoems.password}}"
```

To

```
[[transport.jms.sender]]
name = "SenderTIBCOFactory_topic"
parameter.initial_naming_factory = "com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory"
parameter.provider_url = "{{tibcoems.provider_url}}"
parameter.connection_factory_name = "{{tibcoems.topics_factory_name}}"
parameter.jms_spec_version = "1.0.2b"
parameter.connection_factory_type = "topic"
parameter.'java.naming.security.principal' = "{{tibcoems.username}}"
parameter.'java.naming.security.credentials' = "{{tibcoems.password}}"
```